# How to increment build number with Gradle and/or IntelliJ automatically?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, build, build-numbers

How to increment build number with Gradle and/or IntelliJ?

The question is not related with Android, it is normal Java App.

Increment should occur either on each build or on special task run.

I have following line in my `build.gradle`

```
version = '0.1.3-SNAPSHOT'
```

apparently, this doesn't contain build part?

Answer (score 0):

You can use gradle release plugin, and you can auto increment releases.

https://github.com/researchgate/gradle-release